# Dovecot Mailbox Encryption (Scrambler) - pem_lib.c fails to handle key

Tags: mysql, dovecot, openssl, encryption

In addition to [following](https://serverfault.com/questions/850536/dovecot-scrambler-plugin-mysql-password-user-query-fails) post, Dovecot ran into problems while reading the public key from the DB:

```
Error: scrambler_pem_read_public_key: 139640300201616:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: PUBLIC KEY
```

There seems to be a problem with the key-format, even if it is formated in pem according to [this](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken/issues/68) post.

I tried different column-data-types(blob, text) and inserted the key to the table user_keys in this way, but did't solve the problem:

```
insert into user_keys (uid, enabled_encryp, public_key, private_key, private_key_salt) values (1, true,'-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
mQENBFkdy48BCAC9FsBgeLEmkmr5UZcS/bnrQpAcewatETpkE3IAQFxu1lhErmtu
nyioZ8Oa1e+Xc6KIGk690vMbEmApifIi2FIlnDkVh3Wh1mP3he6HGRs7BgLfl9fc
m6QSvjuosmWGMyZ1LiuPtoulXDiHolwGUcLPr5YifazjwdB0pPeFUnpo6kbw4XdF
...
fBiRS4dBoKz1Jwp5EvGbM3oh9RtDz6qK69cHZ0nKy9ErYjHS0Kw/fKFaou2T3P71
sFuvxOHojGhmxQQRw2ZSOfRgLaG1lpohAF0KNlIsGV5WQSU
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----','-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
lQO+BFkdy48BCAC9FsBgeLEmkmr5UZcS/bnrQpAcewatETpkE3IAQFxu1lhErmtu
nyioZ8Oa1e+Xc6KIGk690vMbEmApifIi2FIlnDkVh3Wh1mP3he6HGRs7BgLfl9fc
m6QSvjuosmWGMyZ1LiuPtoulXDiHolwGUcLPr5YifazjwdB0pPeFUnpo6kbw4XdF
...
mzN6IfUbQ8+qiuvXB2dJysvRK2Ix0tCsP3yhWqLtk9z+9bBbr8Th6IxoZsUEEcNm
Ujn0YC2htZaaIQBdCjZSLBleVkEl

-----END PRIVATE KEY-----', 'wZDlM/BRQwCnOVcA');
```

Any help is welcome!